# box shadow not rendering over content

Tags: html, rendering, shadow

so this is driving me crazy.  I have two divs, floated left, the bottom one has a drop shadow box shadow, in this JS fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/q79Lg/ the shadow renders correctly, it covers the content, but when I copy literally the exact same thing to a page http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_backup2.html the shadow doesn't cover the content in the div above.  Why is this happening??

Ultimately I'd like to use it here http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_backup5.html but it's just the same issue as listed in the first two sources, but I've taken all the other garbage out.

Thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: It looks to me that the shadow is there just like it is supposed to, it is just not easy to see against the already dark background.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div align="center" style="background: #ffffff; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 5; border:1px solid red; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-box-shadow: 0px -7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); box-shadow: 0px -7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); width:100%;height:200px;">
```

for the botttom div, see if that works :)

Comment: so I'd like to avoid positioning it absolutely.  And based on the Jfiddle render I don't have to, it works perfectly fine there, you can see the shadow ontop of the image thumb content in the first div that scrolls.  It covers the background in both, but in the Jfiddle is covers the thumbs and scroller as well, which is what I want.  I can't figure out why the live example on the page doesn't.  That is the issue.

Comment: so the above code doesn't work on the website? I'm just curios in trying to find this out, but interestingly "http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_backup2.html" works fine in my browser (firefox) what browser are you using?

Comment: does jfiddle handle code differently in some way that would account for this difference?

Comment: maybe, I don't know, all I know is it works fine for me on the website and in jsfiddle, so I can only assume that jsfiddle handles code differently.

Comment: I'm in chrome, but firefox didnt' work correctly for me. I'm seeing this

Comment: Hmmmm thats curious, but I know what you mean now, but I think positioning it absolute, is the best option, why don't you want to do that?

Comment: and when I change to absolute if effects everything after it and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It should still work, if instead of `bottom: 0px;` you use `top: x px;` It will be positioned further down

Comment: it becomes http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_backup5.html vs http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_backup4.html the first one being what I want over all minus the issue being talked about here.

Comment: actually it is fine except for that footer now is up at the top, I had made taht stay at the very bottom with a wrapper div, not sure how to fix that.

Comment: the easiest way is also to position absolute that (I know I love position absolute :P) and set the top equal to 2300px; i think that worked on my screen try that and it should put it at the bottom of that page

Comment: ...after all of that I got it to work with floating the two divs in question both left....which I thought I had done, this avoids the position absolute.  Lenny dude thanks for spending so much time trying to help me with that.  Couldn't post it as answered so I have to put the solution here.